# What would cause a led light to turn off after one second?

Tags: electrical

I have an older house for number of years. I got tired of the old kitchen light and decided to replace it with led light. I bought a kitchen led light that is oval in shape and takes two 13 inches circular bulbs. After installing I turned on the switch to on position the light comes on but it only light up for one second.  I turned off the switch and turned back on after ten minutes.  The light come back on for a second and turned back off the switch is still on postion. What is the problem can i fix it by myself?
     Thanks
         Ben.

Comment: I am guessing there is a loose wire feeding the circuit. just enough to allow for power up then they die. Have you verified the hot (black) and neutral (White) wire connections? What is the type (model # of the new lamps / fixture).

Answer (score 3):

We've seen the "one second" thing [before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51821/why-are-my-led-bulbs-pulsing-flashing).  The issue was an electronic switch (dimmer, motion sensor, etc.) which used a 2-wire installation - it's designed to work in a traditional "switch loop" where it has no access to neutral.  It sits in series with the light bulb.  When off, it exploits the fact that incandescent bulbs have very low impedance when unlit. When on, it's counting on a lot of current flow through the incandescent.  These devices do not play well with CFL/LED.

Perhaps it's a dimmer and you don't even realize it. Some dimmers look exactly like plain light switches, just with a range of positions.

Upshot: check out the switch, replace.  Switches (which aren't dimmers) are about a buck.

Comment: I’ve seen this as well with built-in-night-light switches.

Answer (score 0):

1. connect the lamp to AC power.
2. Make lamp power switch to auto position.
3. Switch off & on wall AC Switch fast 2-3 times within 3-4 seconds.

It will reset your lamp circuit.
If there is no good result, repeat step 1,2, and 3 again.
Good luck.

Udaya

Comment: ?? This doesn’t appear to make much sense.